# SQL How can I create a condition that augments the count by 1 if they have an appointment

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a sql query where I need to get the **number of days** that a doctor has appointments in a month . If for instance doctor A has 5 appointments today then that will count as 1, if Doctor A also has 6 appointments tomorrow that will also count as 1 so that Doctor A now has a total of 2 days of appointment so far this month. This is my query below essentially I need to get the number of days that a doctor had an appointment during the month of December . December has 31 days so a doctor can have 20 appointments out of 31 or 12 out of 31 etc. Any help would be great. I'm pretty sure it's a condition needed

```
 select distinct()cast(apptdatetime as date) as AptDate, p.lastname as Lastname,p.firstname as Firstname,p.NPI,count(*) as ApptCount from appointment a 
inner join provider p on p.providerid=a.providerid
inner join campaignprovider cp on cp.providerid=p.providerid
where cast(apptdatetime as date) between '12/01/2017' and '12/31/2017'                     
group by cast(apptdatetime as date),p.lastname,p.firstname,p.NPI
order by cast(apptdatetime as date),p.lastname,p.firstname,p.NPI
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Just did I am using SQL Server 2012

Comment: Have a look here,  it might help you find an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21834663/count-unique-number-of-days-between-2-dates-where-each-day-will-have-multiple-ro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `count(distinct)`:

```
select p.lastname as Lastname, p.firstname as Firstname, p.NPI,
       count(distinct cast(apptdatetime as date)) as daycount,
       count(*) as apptcount
from appointment a inner join
     provider p
     on p.providerid = a.providerid inner join
     campaignprovider cp
     on cp.providerid = p.providerid
where cast(apptdatetime as date) between '2017-12-01' and '2017-12-31'
group by p.lastname, p.firstname, p.NPI
order by p.lastname, p.firstname, p.NPI;
```

Answer (score 1):

First: why do you need to cast the date? Isn't it possible to just have the column type set correctly?

Otherwise: what you describe is simply a distinct count on the date value of each appointment. You can group by month and then divide by number of days in that month, which can be achieved by an expression and function call respectively.

Something along these lines:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(appointment_datetime)), 
    DAY(LAST_DAY(appointment_datetime)),
    last_name 
FROM 
    table 
GROUP BY 
    MONTH(appointment_datetime), 
    last_name;
```